# Pass several parameters to the datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to change dateformat, month names and week names of the JQuery datepicker.
This is what I have

```
$(function () {
             var dateFormat = { dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' };
             var danishDays = { dayNamesMin: ["Ma", "Ti", "On", "To", "Fr", "Lø", "Sø"]};
             var danishMonths = { monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"]};

             $("#TilSalgFraTextBox").datepicker( danishMonths);
             $("#TilSalgTilTextBox").datepicker( danishDays);

         });
```

The problem is that I can only pass one value (so it seems) to the datepicker, but I wante to do something like this:

```
$("#TilSalgFraTextBox").datepicker( danishMonths, danishNames, dateFormat);
```

But this doesnt work.
I also tried this:

```
             $("#TilSalgFraTextBox").datepicker( danishMonths);                 
             $("#TilSalgFraTextBox").datepicker( danishDays);
             $("#TilSalgTilTextBox").datepicker( dateFormat);
```

Searching for help, all the examples I could find, was for changing just one value
and this doesn't work either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you could do:

```
var format = 'dd-mm-yy';
var danishdays = ["Ma", "Ti", "On", "To", "Fr", "Lø", "Sø"];
var danishmonths = ["Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"];

$("#TilSalgFraTextBox").datepicker({
  dateFormat: format,
  dayNamesMin: danishdays,
  monthNames: danishmonths
});
```

Comment: @user1960836 you could mark it as Accepted Answer if it solved your problem..!